# cupy code is not fast enough compared with numpy

Tags: python, cupy

Im new in cupy and I have been playing a little with numpy and cupy for comparing the execution time.

```py
import cupy 
import cupyx
import numpy as np
import time

def test_cupy(a0,a1,ind_i,ind_j):

        t1=time.time()
        for i in range(300):
            cupyx.scatter_add(a0,(ind_i,ind_j),cupy.exp(-(ind_i+ind_j)))
            cupyx.scatter_add(a1,(ind_i,ind_j),cupy.exp(-(ind_i+ind_j)))
        t2=time.time()
        print("cupy",t2-t1)
        return t2-t1

def test_numpy(a0,a1,ind_i,ind_j):

        t1=time.time()
        for i in range(300):
            np.add.at(a0,(ind_i,ind_j),np.exp(-(ind_i+ind_j)))
            np.add.at(a1,(ind_i,ind_j),np.exp(-(ind_i+ind_j)))
        t2=time.time()
        print("numpy",t2-t1)
        return t2-t1

a_np=np.zeros((20000,20000)) + 1
a_cp=cupy.zeros((20000,20000)) + 1

ind_np=np.arange(np.shape(a_np)[0])
ind_cp=cupy.arange(np.shape(a_np)[0])

t_cupy=test_cupy(a_cp,a_cp,ind_cp,ind_cp)
t_numpy=test_numpy(a_np,a_np,ind_np,ind_np)

print(t_numpy/t_cupy)
```

I have an Geforce gtx 1080 with 2560 cores, and the time ratio t_numpy/t_cupy is of 18.. much slower than what I've spected. How could I achieve a better perfomance?

Comment: CuPy's computation runs asynchronously to the host, so synchronization is needed before stopping the timer to correctly measure the computation time. One idea is to insert `cupy.cuda.Device().synchronize()` just above `t2=time.time()` (OUTSIDE the for loop) in `test_cupy`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment!! I did it and the speed up is the same! How could I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I recommend you to start from profiling the code using `nvvp` or Nsight.)

The code does not look computation-heavy, so the memory read/write or kernel launch cost would be the bottleneck. One way is to fuse the elementwise operations into one kernel, using `cupy.fuse`.

```
@cupy.fuse
def exp_add_neg(ind_i, ind_j):
    return cupy.exp(-(ind_i + ind_j))

...
cupyx.scatter_add(a0, (ind_i, ind_j), exp_neg_add(ind_i, ind_j))
cupyx.scatter_add(a1, (ind_i, ind_j), exp_neg_add(ind_i, ind_j))
```

It makes ~30% speedup in my environment.

Comment: I used it with this code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786923/typeerror-unsupported-type-type-numpy-ndarray, I observe the numpy is faster than cupy, please could you tell me, why?